# replace a string in file with awk (like sed -i does)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have an Openwrt wireless config file.
Format is like this:

```
config wifi-iface 'priv'
    option device 'radio0'
    option ifname 'priv0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option encryption 'psk-mixed'
    option macfilter 'allow'
    option macfile '/tmp/mac_filter_priv'
    option disabled '1'
    option hidden '1

config wifi-iface 'orphan'
    option device 'radio0'
```

What I need to do is find exactly wifi-iface 'priv' and change option disabled from 1 to 0.
I tried to do it with awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=0} /wifi-iface \47priv/{f=1} {if(f==1 && $2=="disabled")
 {gsub("1", "0"); f=0; print}}' wireless
```

Seems fine but I can't do it interactively so file not changed. How to do that if awk doesn't support -i option?

Comment: Can you run multiple commands separated by semicolons or `&&`?  You could always copy the file, overwrite the original, then delete the copy in one go.  For example: `cp wireless wireless.bak && awk 'code goes here' wireless.bak > wireless && rm wireless.bak`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` command with null `RS` (record separator):

```
awk -v RS= '/wifi-iface \047priv/{sub(/option disabled [^\n]*/, 
       "option disabled \047" 0 "\047"); print $0 ORS; next} 1' config
config wifi-iface 'priv'
    option device 'radio0'
    option ifname 'priv0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option encryption 'psk-mixed'
    option macfilter 'allow'
    option macfile '/tmp/mac_filter_priv'
    option disabled '0'
    option hidden '1
config wifi-iface 'orphan'
    option device 'radio0'
```

Comment: Thanks, But It also removed all empty lines which I would prefer to keep.

Comment: That can be achieved by using `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '...'` above.

Comment: Yes my mistake, I was trying with `FPAT` initially then changed to current solution.

Comment: Don't use `\x27`, use `\047` instead. Try `awk 'BEGIN{print "\047foo!\047"}'` and `awk 'BEGIN{print "\x27foo!\x27"}'` to see why (see also http://awk.freeshell.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#toc12).

Answer (score 0):

Must it be `awk`?  You could use `sed`, which does have a `-i` option:

```
sed -i "/^config wifi-iface 'priv'/,/^config /s/\( disabled\) '1'/\1 '0'/" wireless
```

Here, the leading address pair restricts the `s` command to the section with the iface 'priv'.

Comment: sed works fine, thanks ) I decided to know how the powerful awk can do the trick :)

Comment: `sed -i "/^config wifi-iface 'priv'/,/option disabled/ s/ '1'/ '0'/" wireless`

Comment: Costas, that will also edit any options before "disabled" that happen to have a '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for `-i inplace` (and tidying up the script):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/config wifi-iface / { f = (/\047priv\047/ ? 1 : 0) }
f && $2=="disabled" { sub(/1/,"0") }
{ print }

$ awk -i inplace -f tst.awk file

$ cat file
config wifi-iface 'priv'
    option device 'radio0'
    option ifname 'priv0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option encryption 'psk-mixed'
    option macfilter 'allow'
    option macfile '/tmp/mac_filter_priv'
    option disabled '0'
    option hidden '1

config wifi-iface 'orphan'
    option device 'radio0'
```

With any other awk you can always do (as with any UNIX command):

```
awk -f tst.awk file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

or if you are severely allergic to tmp files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/config wifi-iface / { f = (/\047priv\047/ ? 1 : 0) }
f && $2=="disabled" { sub(/1/,"0") }
{ rec = rec $0 RS }
END { close(FILENAME); printf "%s", rec > FILENAME }

$ awk -f tst.awk file

$ cat file
config wifi-iface 'priv'
    option device 'radio0'
    option ifname 'priv0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option encryption 'psk-mixed'
    option macfilter 'allow'
    option macfile '/tmp/mac_filter_priv'
    option disabled '0'
    option hidden '1

config wifi-iface 'orphan'
    option device 'radio0'
```

Comment: As I said there is no -i inplace option. I was thinking about solution without tmp files but there is no such one. Also now I know sed -i does the trick same way - with tmp file.

Comment: You absolutely can do it without a tmp file in non-GNU awk, it's just not worth the bother. I'll edit my question to show it. Done.